# Gradient alpha centered around 0 in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot densities by groups such that the alpha value decreases (more transparent) as the x axis value gets closer to 0.

Based on the `data` dataset, I generate the alpha column by rescaling the x axis values around 0.

I thought that adding the `alpha` inside the `aes()` would work but this throws and error.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(scales)

set.seed(123)
data <- tibble(A = rnorm(100),
               B = rnorm(100, mean = -0.7),
               C = rnorm(100, mean = 1)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
               names_to = "model") %>% 
  group_by(model) %>% 
  summarise(value = list(value)) %>%
  mutate( xval = map(value, ~density(.x)$x),
          yval = map(value, ~density(.x)$y)) %>% 
  select(-value) %>% 
  unnest(ends_with("val"))

#create alpha column
df <- data %>% 
  group_by(model) %>% 
  mutate(myalpha = abs(scale(xval, center = 0)), #scale to center around 0
         myalpha2 = scales::rescale_mid(myalpha, mid = 0) #rescale 0-1, 0 for values around 0
         ) %>% 
  as_tibble() 

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = xval, y = yval,
             fill = model, col = model))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+
  geom_density(aes(alpha = myalpha2), #alpha white around 0
               stat = "identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "pink", "orange"))+
  scale_alpha_identity()
#> Error in `f()`:
#> ! Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot yet have a gradient fill in native ggplot (this includes gradients on the alpha channel). You can give the appearance of gradient fills using vertical line segments whose individual alpha values change along the x axis though.

Note that your alpha calculation isn't quite right here. `myalpha2` has a minimum of 0.5 at the 0 point, as you can easily check with `min(df$myalpha2)`.

To fix this, and implement the vertical line segment hack, you can do:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(myalpha2 = 2 * (as.vector(myalpha2) - 0.5)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = xval, y = yval))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+
  geom_segment(aes(alpha = myalpha2, xend = xval, yend = 0, color = model), 
               size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "pink", "orange"))+
  scale_alpha_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: Upvote but why `fill`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas you're right. This isn't needed. Thanks.

Comment: Without the `fill` I'm getting a lot of dark regions on the non-intersecting sections.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great workaround. How would you adjust the alpha to make the gradient wider or narrower ?

Comment: @CyG I would try raising `myalpha2` to different powers. For example, `myalpha2^2` to make the gradient wider, ot `myalpha2^0.5` to make it narrower. Any value from 0 to infinity should work, as the values will all be constrained to [0,1]